# How to make .net application using oracle database oracle client independent

Tags: c#-4.0, oracle11g

I have developed an application for internal database operation of my organization.My application in developed in C# with oracle is as Database.For running application on any machine in LAN i have to install oracle client on the each machine is there any mechanism so that i need not to install oracle client for running application.

Answer (score 0):

You can bundle your application with the [Oracle Instant Client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index.html). Unfortunately, at some 120 MB it is rather big.

Or, you could use the new Managed ODP.NET driver: http://www.nuget.org/packages/odp.net.managed/